# php building / populating an Array of Arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have seen alot of tutorial on how to get the data out of a 2D array but I need to build one similar to this and I have not found any logic I can follow:

```
$array = array("socks" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "shirts"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
```

I cant seem to figure out the logic to even start the code....

```
for each clothingType // I did this
  get options // I did this
    for each option //I did this
       add to the clothingOption Array //... help!
```

Im only stuck on the building of the clothingOption 2D Array

could it be someting like

```
foreach clothingType as $kClothes =>VClothes
    get Options
      for each Options as $kOptions =>$VOption
      $array[$VClothes][]= $VOption
```

Thanks and I hope this is not too vague....

Comment: I really don't understand the need for the question.  You have built the array you want in your very first code example? It doesn't seem like you have a case where the "options" have the same values across types to where you could gain some flexibility by making an array that represents a Cartesian join of types and options, so why not define it the way you have? Perhaps your example is too trivial to explain what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
<?php
function getMe($type) {
  //do some processing and construct array
 return array('a','b','c');
}

$myTypes = array('type1','type2','type3');
$answer = array();
foreach($myTypes as $val) {
  $answer[$val] = getMe($val);
}

print_r($answer);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [type1] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) [type2] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) [type3] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) )
```

Comment: Thanks footy. This helps!  .. Mike just to explain, the values are variables comeing in from a data feed so I could not just assign the values like that. I was just giving that array as an example of what I needed as the outcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe (sorry for errors - by hand):

```
//$array = array("socks" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
//           "shirts"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));

$types = array('socks', 'shirts');
$socks = array("blue", "red", "green");
$shirts = array("small", "medium", "large");
$array = array();
foreach ($types as $type) {
    foreach($$type as $cloth) {
        $array[$type][] = $cloth;
    }
}
print_r($array);
```